# How do you reference a div from a separate JSX file and send it to another JSX file

Tags: reactjs, ref

So I have app.jsx which calls up all my other JSX files.
This way I have each component organized in its own file.
I would like to navigate to each section of the website (all on one page just different areas). The only issue is I can't seem to reference where
I want to go to. I thought if I referenced the imported jsx file it would get its DOM elements. But that's not working. What seems to work is if I have a div directly being referenced in the same App.jsx file. But I need to get the child div element.

```
function App() {
  const aboutmeOnClickRef = useRef(null);
  const portfolioOnClickRef = useRef(null);
  const employmentOnClickRef = useRef(null);
  const educationOnClickRef = useRef(null);
  const letschatOnClickRef = useRef(null);

  return (
<div className="app">
  <Topbar
    aboutmeOnClickRef={aboutmeOnClickRef}
    portfolioOnClickRef={portfolioOnClickRef}
    employmentOnClickRef={employmentOnClickRef}
    educationOnClickRef={educationOnClickRef}
    letschatOnClickRef={letschatOnClickRef}
  />

  <div className="sections">
    <Intro />
    <DisplayAboutMe ref={aboutmeOnClickRef} />
    <Portfolio ref={portfolioOnClickRef} />
    <Employment ref={employmentOnClickRef} />
    <Education ref={educationOnClickRef} />
    <LetsChat ref={letschatOnClickRef} />
  </div>
</div>
  );
}

//This is what I want to do, but doesn't work
//const DisplayAboutMe = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <AboutMe ref={ref} />);

//This one works but creates a whole new div and doesn't get my jsx file
const DisplayAboutMe = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <div ref={ref} />);
```

AboutMe.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./aboutme.module.scss";

export default function AboutMe() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.aboutme} id={styles.aboutme}></div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you need refs for navigation, but if you'd like us to point out what's missing ref-wise, you'll need to show us the code for `AboutMe`. AboutMe will need to use forwardRef (It's not enough to have DisplayAboutMe use forwardRef)

Comment: @NicholasTower I'm open to ideas of better ways to do this. I'm new to React so I could well be missing something much easier. I have also updated the question to include AboutMe.jsx :)

Comment: Ok, maybe you can describe what you're trying to do. Is it something like "if the url is /about-me, show `<AboutMe>` component and no other sections"?

Comment: @NicholasTower Well originally i was using <a href="#.... to navigate and all was fine. But then I started having conflict with my .scss files and class names so I made them all modules. (aboutme.module.scss) This solved my class conflicts, but then stopped me from referencing id to navigate using <a href and so I have now being going down a rabbit hole of solutions to which I can't find one that works. Hopefully this helps explain my situation.

Comment: Ok, so all of the sections are on the screen simultaneously, and when they click a link you want to scroll the page to a certain anchor?

Comment: Exactly. I was thinking if I could reference the top div of each section I would get to where I need to go.

Comment: K, then the refs make some sense after all. I'll add an answer showing what you're missing for the refs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, refs to function components don't do anything. You need to use forwardRef to tell react which dom element you want the ref to point to. Currently, your about me component doesn't do this. Here's what it might look like:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./aboutme.module.scss";

const AboutMe = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className={styles.aboutme} id={styles.aboutme}></div>
  );
});

export default AboutMe
```

With the above change, you shouldn't need DisplayAboutMe. App can render an `<AboutMe>` and pass in a ref, and the ref will be assigned the div that's inside AboutMe.

```
function App() {
  const aboutmeOnClickRef = useRef(null);
  // ...

  <div className="sections">
    <Intro />
    <AboutMe ref={aboutmeOnClickRef} />
  </div>
  // ...
}

// In topBar:

function TopBar(props) {
  return (
    // ...
    <a onClick={() => { props.aboutMeOnClickRef.current.scrollIntoView() }}/>
    // ...
  )
}
```